# Determine if key values in two arrays are equal then update if they are

Tags: php

I've taken up PHP programming as a hobby after work and kids. So, my appologies if this code is bogus...but I've been searching for awhile. Anyways, I am trying to compare the values in two arrays and...where each key value equals another I would like to update that value to '1'. So for example, in one array the values are (2, 4, 1) in the second they are (3, 4, 5). Afterwards the the values that would be in my sql column would be updated to (2, 1, 1). Here is my code. Thank you for any help!

```
$array1 = mysql_fetch_array($x);
$array2 = mysql_fetch_array($x1);

foreach($array1 as $key => $value)
{
if($value == $array2[$key])
{
   $v = "UPDATE fXnumber SET xnumber = '1'";
   mysql_query($v);
}


}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Looks like you're keeping the value from $array1 if they don't match?  It'd also make your question better if you clarified what wasn't working.  It looks like you want to update the DB.  Do you also want to update $array1?

Comment: I think `mysql_fetch_array`, without the second parameter, will return an array with each column listed twice: with column's name and column's ordinal position. Keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Check when you update table set id for identifier which record will be updated

```
$array1 = mysql_fetch_array($x);
$array2 = mysql_fetch_array($x1);

foreach($array1 as $key => $value)
{
    if (isset($array2[$key]) && $value == $array2[$key])
    {
       $v = "UPDATE fXnumber SET xnumber = 1 WHERE id = '{$key}'";
       mysql_query($v);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a version of your code with enhanced reasability. And I added an (currently invalid) 'WHERE' clause. I assume your sql statement in the version you suggesteed did not only update a single value in the database table as expected and desired, but _all values inside that table. most likely you want to specify *which* entry to update:

```
$array1 = mysql_fetch_array($x);
$array2 = mysql_fetch_array($x1);

foreach(array_keys($array1) as $key) 
{
    if ( $array1[$key]==$array2[$key] ) 
    {
        $v = sprintf("UPDATE fXnumber SET xnumber=1 WHERE id=%s", $key);
        mysql_query($v);
    }
}
```

Another hint: phps old mysql extension is depreciated. It has lots of issues. Consider using the newer mysqli extension or, even better, use the PDO abstraction layer. It protects you from code injection and the like.

Comment: I am afraid I am going to have to be dragged across the finish line. I am not able to make either of these solutions work (no update in sql table). You are right, with my current code all the values are updated in my xnumber sql column. The values I am looking to update are -any- values in my xnumber sql column that are equal to their counterpart(?) in the setnumber sql column. So for example (3, 5, 2, 7) in xnumber column compared to setnumber column (2, 5, 6, 7) would lead to the xnumber column values being updated to (3, 1, 2, 1). Perhaps the WHERE id is my problem.

Comment: Ok, if we have to we _will_ drag you :-) Let's sort things out: first we need your table layout. Otherwise it is pretty cumbersome to construct sql statements... Please edit the question and add that information. Oh, and also the sql querys you use to get the two arrays in the first place...

Comment: Am I right that you are comparing the values in two tables and updating one of the original tables? In that case the solution might be much easier and more efficient to implement that in pure sql. A single sql statement doing the update withoout any need for a php script. At least without having to process the tables line by line... Also a reason why posting the tables and queries makes sense.

Comment: oh...I found the answer...$sql_query4 = "UPDATE fXnumber SET xnumber = 0 WHERE xnumber = setnumber";
mysql_query($sql_query4);

Comment: Great, that was what I meant! Congratulations!

Answer (score -1):

For array comparing [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) might help.

Comment: what is the problem with it? You get empty array if there are no differences. No obvious iterations, cleaner code. Also there is associative array_diff

Comment: I downvoted since the return from `array_diff` only returns the difference.  The original question seems to want to keep the different values, and put a 1 in when the two values match, and with array_diff you'd lost that position information.

Comment: To clarify, this would have been fine as a comment.  It's not an answer as it doesn't solve the question.